# Video View Not Working with URI

Tags: android, android-videoview

When intent is fired for recording video on button click, it is recording that but in onActivityResult() method it is not playing the video.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private VideoView videoView;
static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_RECORD = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_video_button);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.display_video_view);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchVideoIntent();
        }
    });
}

private void dispatchVideoIntent() {
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if(videoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(videoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_RECORD);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_RECORD && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoView.start();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `videoUri`? What messages of relevance are showing up in LogCat?

Comment: There is no error in LogCat. What happening is recorded video is not appearing in videoView. What I have to do to make the recorded video to play in that view.

Comment: What is the value of `videoUri`?